# Is it appropriate to grow up Vistior implementation instances from spring beans?

Tags: java, spring, design-patterns, visitor-pattern

I have the following implementation of Visitor:

```
public class RecipientsGenerator implements RecipientTypeVisitor<List<Integer>>{

    //Spring bean
    private RecipientService<?> recipientService;
    //Spring bean
    private DynamicGroupService dynamicGroupService;

    public List<Integer> visit(RecipientSetType t) {
        //Impl
    }

    public List<Integer> visit(DynamicGroupType t) {
        //Impl  
    }

    public List<Integer> visit(StaticGroupType t) {
        //Impl
    }
}
```

and the visitor interface itself:

```
public interface RecipientTypeVisitor<ReturnType> {
    public ReturnType visit(RecipientSetType t);

    public ReturnType visit(DynamicGroupType t);

    public ReturnType visit(StaticGroupType t);
}
```

I need to use this RecipientGenerator within a controller in order to show recipients identifiers.

```
private List<Integer> getRecipientIds() {
    RecipientType t;
    //obtaining the type
    RecipientTypeVisitor<?> visitor = new RecipientsGenerator();
    return (List<Integer>) t.accept(visitor);
}
```

My question is, what is the better way to obtain the instances of the services?

1. (We don't put the Visitor into a spring config)

   ApplicationContext ctx = ContextLoader.getCurrentWebApplicationContext();
   ctx.getBean("dynamicGroupService");
2. We put it into a spring config and inject the services. But in that case we couldn't just apply `new RecipientsGenerator();` to create the intance of the visitor.